# How to add Ads which contain list of Application in Android?

Tags: android, admob, ads, googleads-mobile-unity

I would like to add Ads like show in below images.

1. On icon click, it should open list of applications.
2. And on app click, it should redirect to play store.

[image: On click Icon it open list of apps]

[image: List of Apps]

Please someone help to add this Ads in my App. Thanks

Comment: Please read https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/

Comment: @Rahulrr2602 thanks a lot bro..!

Comment: @Rahulrr2602 do you have idea about ad like amazon app. for example clean master have amazon icon and xender have gift icon.

Comment: @TusharLathiya Sorry for the late reply. You can try having a look at this offer https://affiliate-program.amazon.com/ which is called affiliate ads. The revenue calculation of these ads are done like this suppose your user buys an item from Amazon using the link provided by you or from your app then you will get certain % of the purchase. The % depends on the type of item. You can research more on this to get what is exactly needed by you.

Comment: @Rahulrr2602 now i got relevant ans for my question..thnx a lot again.

Comment: @Tushar Lathiya Glad it helped you.